# Cannot connect to Internet on 11.04 using BSNL EVDO Prithvi Card

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, wireless, internet-connection

I cannot connect to Internet using *BSNL EVDO Prithvi data card*. Went through some websites that offered help, installed `wvdial` package and tried again, but was unsuccessful.

I have Read that, Ubuntu 11.04 automatically detects Data Card, You only need to configure "*Network Manager"* and it will work, I did exactly that, but the result is same.

The OS detects the data card, and the presence of network , but it cannot login.

I have read in some forums that Ubuntu 11.04 does not have support for *BSNL EVDO Prithvi*, is it true?

I re-checked the "User ID" and "Password". Its working on Windows.

Please help me fix this.

Comment: Can somebody help me out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joy,
I could make it work with wvdial just now! Even I have the same BSNL EVDO with the Prithvi dongle, and it does not connect using the Network Manager (but others like docomo do). Try the following:

Configure wvdial with correct number (#777), your username, password and Stupid Mode = 1. This I presume you would have already tried. Now, if on running wvdial, you are able to see till secondary DNS getting allocayed, try this one last step. This is what saved me:

> You might have issues with resolvconf stomping on your DNS
>   configuration in /etc/resolv.conf - but if you're getting an IP
>   address from the remote peer then the modem is working, even if you
>   can't access any websites etc. **If you don't use resolvconf, consider
>   just uninstalling it.**

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NetworkManager/Hardware/3G/Probing

Comment: i tried using wvdial dude, but will try again with the mentioned setting! btw how do i know if i use resolvconf ? i guess the Q is dumb but i just dunno :(

Comment: It works dude! **resolvconf** was the culprit, but does it have other effects on the system?

Comment: However one issue is there, the Software Centre does not detect the connection hence won't install!!! Any fix for this?